# Error loading Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows

I am new to linux. Installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10(UEFI). Ubuntu getting loaded fine. But getting error while loading Windows 10. 
Error description - ...Can't load image...

Boot repair report - http://paste.ubuntu.com/15071525/

Device - Acer Aspire Laptop. 
Secure boot is enabled but not able to change it(grayed out). Appreciate the help from any one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the pastebin.
As per the pastebin

**
Please disable SecureBoot in the BIOS. Then try again.Do you want to continue?
**

So before the boot process , get into your BIOS and disable secure boot completely and then try boot-repair process all over again.

Comment: Thanks Ashu. As mentioned in the question I am unable to disable the secure boot option in UEFI (Option is greyed out). Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: Enabled secureboot  prevent Ubuntu like O/s to get installed and loaded. It impacts grub2 also. Read about it here 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/493409/is-disabing-secure-boot-needed-for-ubuntu-14-04-dual-boot-with-windows-8-uefi'

Comment: My issue is resolved now. Found a way to disable secure boot and ran boot-repair again. Then Selected Ubuntu as a first boot option in UEFI. Now I can select Ubuntu or Windows from GRUB.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Santhosh. glad to know that. Please accept this answer by clicking tick mark.