# Katoolin messed up with the PCI cards

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, katoolin, kali-linux-tools

I installed Katoolin using which I downloaded all the 'Information Gathering' tools. Midway there came a prompt to allow access to DHCP which I allowed. Since then my PC has started misbehaving. **Whenever I reboot, either the ethernet is found working or the wifi card. But not both simultaneously.** I mean the PC can't even identify the lan cable is connected or not and the Ethernet is shown as unclaimed. I have provided outputs from various commands down below for your convenience.

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 179c (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

sudo lshw -class network

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: 40:49:0f:5a:b3:45
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-32-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 ip=192.168.1.154 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 memory:94200000-943fffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       version: 12
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94404000-94404fff memory:94400000-94403fff
```

UPDATE: I tried removing secure boot from my bios and rebooted Ununtu and the PCI cards worked fine. But when I again turned it off the condition became same as earlier. I would recommend you to read this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/951032/787213

lshw -class Network

```
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: enp4s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 54:ab:3a:b4:76:f4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.046.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.218 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:127 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94404000-94404fff memory:94400000-94403fff
```

Comment: Reviewers: Not off topic. Katoolin is a script that helps to install Kali Linux tools on Ubuntu and other Linux distributions.

Comment: Is the katoolin in the ubuntu repositories and maintained by ubuntu developers? Does it install only from the ubuntu repositories? If the script is not in the ubuntu repos or if it installs from outside the ubuntu repos then, imo, it is off topic as imo the kali tools are highly specialized.  Imo if you want to use these tools run kali

Comment: If you install Katoolin and then check which distro you are running, will it say Ubuntu or will it say Kali Linux? Run the command: cat /etc/os-release

Comment: @Panther  Katoolin first requires us to download kali repositories using which we install the tools. We can also install those individually by cloning specific repositories. After the programs are downloaded you can remove the kali repositories again.

Comment: @Panther  none of the questions you asked are relevant to whether or not this is on topic. If the OP is running Ubuntu, then this is on topic. Whether or not the software they installed came from the Ubuntu repos is irrelevant, users are free to install software from other sources or even compile from source.

Comment: This is on topic, please see [Are "not only Ubuntu-specific" questions on-topic?](//meta.askubuntu.com/q/14523)

Comment: I am afraid we will have to agree to disagree on this topic. I do not think it is reasonable to expect to install and run anything from anywhere just because you installed Ubuntu and, in this case, the kali tools are highly specialized. If there is a bug with the script or any of the tools one could not file a bug report on LP, it would go upstream. So, IMO, we should also turf this question upstream . At any rate I will not close these sorts of questions as you wish but do you have any information to help the OP?